# Reactjs error boundary fallback is not responding

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am throwing an error to test my error boundary but Error boundary fallback ui is  not responding after throwing an error.Here i am trying to click on button but it not clickable.

```
const ErrorBoundaryFallbackComponent = ({ error, resetErrorBoundary }) => {
  return (
    <div id="__layout">
      <button onClick={() => window.history.back()}>Try again</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ErrorBoundaryFallbackComponent
```

Index.js

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './app/Index'
import { Spinner } from 'components'
import FallbackUi from 'components/ErrorBoundaryFallbackComponent'
import { ErrorBoundary } from 'react-error-boundary'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
    <ErrorBoundary
      FallbackComponent={FallbackUi}
      resetKeys={[history.location.pathname]}
    >
      <App />
    </ErrorBoundary>
  </Suspense>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-golick-k23gj5?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: What do you mean by "it not clickable."? Please describe the issue.

Comment: @LinDu:when i try to click on button to go Back in fallback ui, i am not able to click it , it seems this component is also broken but showing the ui

Comment: Can you create a running https://codesandbox.io/ demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @LinDu Here is the sanbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-golick-k23gj5?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1):

Error boundaries do **not** catch errors for:

- Event handlers ([learn more](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#how-about-event-handlers))
- Asynchronous code (e.g. `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks)
- Server side rendering
- Errors thrown in the error boundary itself (rather than its children)

> React doesn’t need error boundaries to recover from errors in event handlers. Unlike the render method and lifecycle methods, the event handlers don’t happen during rendering. So if they throw, React still knows what to display on the screen.

> If you need to catch an error inside an event handler, use the regular JavaScript `try/catch` statement

Error boundaries catch errors during rendering, in lifecycle methods, and in constructors of the whole tree below them.

The below example show the `ErrorBoundary` will catch the error when the `count` state is greater than `1`.

```
import { Suspense, useState } from "react";
import FallbackComponent from "./Fallaback";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { ErrorBoundary } from "react-error-boundary";

const App = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    if (count > 1) {
        throw new Error("Test");
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>increase</button>
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Suspense fallback={<h2>Loading</h2>}>
        <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={FallbackComponent}>
            <App />
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </Suspense>,
    document.getElementById("root"),
);
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76958587-47k96j?file=/src/index.js)